# How would a history of legal actions taken against you affect a career in software?

Tags: software-industry

I'm interested in writing software similar to a commercial product for a personal project, with no intent of competing commercially. The commercial software is however protected by patents. This question isn't about the legal considerations when doing this, which have been hashed out multiple times elsewhere.

There's a very real possibility of receiving a lawsuit or more likely just a C&D.

My question is this: if I were to go forward on the project, and then be forced to take it down, negotiate licensing, or in the worst case pay damages due to patent infringement, how concerned should I be about this reflecting poorly on me to a future employer?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123293/discussion-on-question-by-soundwave-how-would-a-history-of-legal-actions-taken-a).

Comment: I think you are creating a problem that doesn't exist. You cannot breach a patent by making something similar to something else. Patents protect inventions not products.

Comment: US Patents protect against you making and selling something to others, not anything made for personal use only.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of putting in an answer,

- Nobody would even know or care.

How would the topic even arise?

As a student you once had a few lines of code on some git project and you got a letter from a lawyer complaining about it.

Who would even know this?

Fortunately, nothing to worry about!

Further, an XY issue,

> There's a very real possibility of receiving a lawsuit or more likely just a C&D.

My guess is that the good news here is, **you are wildly overthinking this**.

If, beyond all belief, your Xcode project became within the year a mammoth, household name thing making millions and on the news all day (and your legal team happened to mention to you that this week you were sued once or twice, or .. whatever .. you probably wouldn't bother taking meetings with the legal team, as your CEO would be attending to such trivia), would this matter to "your career and getting a job in the future?"  Heh!

Honestly, you're likely wildly overthinking this, in a number of ways.  Enjoy your project!